# Is there a colour code for electron flow notation?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, power-electronics, schematics, electron

I'm building a power supply for electro-chemistry experiments. It would make more sense to have the output correctly denote which terminal is 'electro-negative' and which is 'electro-positive' instead of those colours specified for DC conventional current.

Is there a colour code specification to denote - and + in electron flow notation?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146732/discussion-on-question-by-nobody-loves-you-is-there-a-colour-code-for-electron-f); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

What you ask for exists in the standard red/black convention. There's no need to introduce a separate color code. The colors don't care about whether your calculations use technical or electron flow direction.

And the colors are very clear: black is the more electronegative pole. (no need to put that in quotation marks; it's fixed, established term.)

Comment: What your saying is from the perspective of somebody operating or designing an electrical circuit. When I'm actually trying to make a compound more electronegative, it makes less sense. From a physics and chemistry perspective this does become confusing.

Comment: You keep claiming that, but it's really not confusing. The black "-" pole has always been the one where there's electrons coming from, and the red "+" pole always the one accepting electrons. That's why they're labeled "-" and "+", actually, the "-" is more negative. And it's black. I don't see why anyone would thing "red" would emit electrons? That's never been the case.

Comment: We have textbooks with versions in electron flow and conventional current.  The only thing that changes is the current direction.  It's not the direction that is important, but what the current does.  Red/Black or +/- allows consistency.

Comment: Because Red specifies 'positive', and Black specifies 'negative'. However when connecting experimental equipment, I'm thinking in terms of 'electro positive' and 'electro negative'. It's not the case that it's particularly difficult. It's just one less unnecessary conversion that I have to do.

Comment: @nobody_loves_you you're just confused. "positive" means "electro-positive", ie. "fewer negative charges here". There's no dichtomy here. There's no conversion you have to do. Electrons flow from the negative black to the positive red.

Comment: @nobody_loves_you can you spell out the conversion you say you have to do? Because you'll quickly realize that you're literally the only one here having to do that redundant conversion and everyone else just uses the raw definition being exactly what I (and others) have stated numerous times now: black is the negative (which really means "electro-negative") pole, electrons come from there and travel to the red, positive (which really means "electro-positive") pole.

Comment: Until you have to do electro-chemistry. To make one atom bind to another, I have to remove electrons. The NEGATIVE POLE, conventionally coloured BLACK. Would supply MORE electrons.

Comment: @nobody_loves_you Yes, the negative pole supplies electrons, which makes perfect sense because electrons are negative. I'm still failing to see the confusion?

Comment: yeah, electrons are carriers of *negative* charge. If you want to change that, you're going to confuse *a lot* of physicists. And, as said, you keep repeating that electro-chemists think differently about things, but that's **really** not the case. It really seems like you're the only one confused! Tell you what, the red / black notation actually dates back to the days where DC was exclusively the domain of electrochemists. The confusion is all yours.

Comment: The carrier is and has always been electrons, so conventional current is wrong, so electrons come out of the Black terminal and go towards the Red terminal irregardless of how it is used.  I guess the true issue is what you mean by *building a power supply*?  For us, a power supply is a source to do work, not conduct experiments.

Comment: @nobody_loves_you If you're confused because you think of red as meaning positive and positive as meaning more electrons, then the problem is not the color code; the problem is the way that you're thinking of things. If you use a different color code in order to reduce your own confusion, the result will be that everyone _except_ you will be more confused and will make more mistakes because they have to think about it harder.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think that there is a standard colour for electron flow direction or current direction.

> instead of those colours specified for DC conventional current.

These colours do not indicate anything about current, conventional or otherwise.

The red-is-positive, black-is-negative refers to the voltage of the red wire/terminal is more positive than the voltage of black wire/terminal.

This is universal and should not be messed with. It applies to power supplies and multimeters.

Power supplies generally allow electrons to flow in one direction. They leave the black terminal and enter the red terminal.

However, if the power supply is a rechargeable cell, then electrons can flow both directions depending upon the external circuit. The voltage polarity of the terminals does not change.

In circuits with reactive components and/or more than one source, the adage,”electrons flow from negative to positive” isn’t always true.

So in this sense attempting to colour code flow is impossible.

The colours of the power supply terminals indicate the voltage polarity with respect to each other, nothing more.

A time honoured, worldwide standard.

---

Addition:

One solution might be to reverse the positions of the terminals, in a manner that accentuates the electro-chemical usage.